# Take few seconds to load the scene cocos 2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, delay, transition

I have used

```
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"SongScene.ccbi"] ];
```

For load the next scene. It take a little delay to load the scene. When the second time loading, there is no delay. How can i fix the issue. Songs scene consist of many graphic sprites.

Comment: you want to keep delay to for naxt scene

Comment: loading resources (images specifically) takes time. The 2nd time they're already in memory (cached), that's why it's faster

Comment: How can i minimize the load time.

Comment: If the bulk of the time is consumed loading textures, convert them to .pvr.ccz format, this format loads much faster on all devices. Use TexturePacker.

Answer (score 0):

When you first start your game, create an Intro Scene showing a splash image or loading image, etc.  While that scene is showing, load up the resources that will take a long time to load so that they are already in the cache.

When they are done loading, transition to your main scene(s).  The resources will already be loaded and they will go faster.

You can even create entire scenes like this, you just need  a place to store them off temporarily, such as the child of a CCNode that you use for holding scenes.  Then use them when you need them.

I only learned this recently.  Before that I was loading them at the start of the App, which is a poor choice.